# JAVA Regex gets hanged for some pattern

Tags: regex

Whenever I try matching the regex pattern

```
    PREREQasdasdasdasdsadNot+es3adadaK2+0000000+043YEARA_
```

with

```
    ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*|(([a-zA-Z0-9])+(([_]*|[-]|[+])[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*))$
```

it gets hanged

These are few cases which might help

• positive cases

1. `asdsadas+asd-asdasdad-asdad+asdasd`
2. `UPGRADE+asd-asdasdasdvf-asd`
3. `UPGRADE+asd-adsasda__LS-TasdL+asdasdwd`
4. `UPGRADE+asd-asdasd__LS-TRI+A+L+asdasdwd`
5. `UPG-R-ADE+asd-asd__LS-TRI+A+L+asdasdwd`
6. `PREREQ+asdasdasda-Traveler-asd3YEAR+FK20000000043YEAR-A`
7. `PREREQ+asdasdd-T_raveler-asdasds3YEAR+FK20000000043YEAR-A`
8. `UP_G-R+ADE+asd-ESS__________E+N+T-I_A_LS-TRI+A+L+asdasdwd`
9. `PREREQ+asdad-Traveler-asdasd3YEAR+FK200__0-0+0_00043YEAR-A`
10. `PREREQasdasdasdTravelerasda3YEARFK20000000043YEARA`
11. `UP_G-R+ADE+MTG-ESSENTIA__LS-TRI+A+L+asdasdwd`
12. `PREREQasdasdasdasdvfTravelerasdt+esasd2K2+0000000+043YEARA`

Negative cases

1. `UPG--RADE+asdasd-asdasdasd__LS-TRI+A+L+asdasdwd`
2. `UPG-R-ADE_+_asda-asdasdasd__LS-TRI+A+L+asdasdwd`
3. `UPG-R-ADE+_asd-asdasdad__LS-TRI+A+L+asdasdwd`
4. `UPG-R-ADE+_asd-ESSENTIA__LS-TRI+A+L+asdasdwd`
5. `PREREQ+asdasdasdasdvf-asdr-asd++3YEAR+FK20000000043YEAR-A`
6. `PREREQ_+-asdasdasdasdvf-asdr-Notes3YEAR+-+FK20000000043YEAR-A`
7. `_PREREQ+asdasdasdasdvf-asdr-asd3asdR+FK200__0-0+0_00043YEAR-A`

system hangs(NEG cases)

1. `PREREQ+asdasdasdasdvf-asd-asd3YEAR+-+FK20000000043asdds-A`
2. `PREREQasdasdasdasdvfasdrNot+es3YEARFK2+0000000+043asdasd_`

Comment: the problem is with the last "_"

Comment: the match must fail but its going into loop and getting hanged

Comment: Google "catastrophic backtracking"

Comment: Any clue on how you distinguish positive and negative cases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `\w`

```
^\w+([-+]\w+)*$
```

`\w+` would match `[a-zA-Z\d_]` 1 to many times

Comment: I want it to fail but its going into infinite loop when i use java regex.mathes()

Answer (score 0):

***Corrected (and tested)***

Looking at it:

```
^
(
    [a-zA-Z0-9]*
    |
    (
        ([a-zA-Z0-9])+
        (
            ([_]*|[-]|[+])
            [a-zA-Z0-9]+
        )*
    )
)
$
```

One may simplify it to:

```
^(
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+
    (
        ([_]+|[-+])
        [a-zA-Z0-9]+
    )*
)?$
```

where I also corrected `_*` to `_+` otherwise the underscore would fit at every position on every looping occasion: exponential. That caused the hang: `(_* ...)*`.

```
   ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(([_]+|[-+])[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)?$
```

Regex fail on such things unfortunately, almost something like the halting problem.

Comment: `\w` is not exactly a replacement for `[_]+`... But you could just write `_+`.

Comment: @rednaw what I wanted to say was `[_]+` is not required.at all..it can be merged with `\w+`..so you would have this regex `^\w+([-+]\w+)*$` also the above regex won't match the sample input in question

Comment: @Anirudh I don't think the question author tries to match the sample input, the problem is that it's hanging.

Comment: I dont want it to match it must return false when put it in IF() cond